# Assign vertex label as vertex value without changing edgeWeight

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am new to Mathematica. I have drawn a node graph, which has approximate 600 vertices and specific edge weight (as shown below). There is a vertex label in each vertex. I want to assign vertex label as a vertex value. I can do it by this.

```
rplcmntRule = VertexLabels /. Options[g]
newVertices = VertexList[g] /. rplcmntRule;
newEdges = EdgeList[g] /. rplcmntRule
g = Graph[newEdges, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {1/2, 1/2}]]
```

But this method also changes the edge weight. I want to change the vertex only, without changing the edge weight.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can rename vertices using the [`VertexReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace.html) function. It will preserve edge weights.

Be careful not to accidentally introduce duplicate names. This would change the graph structure and also remove edge weights.

Comment: I tried but after VertexReplace, EdgeWeights were gone. Wondering if I did any mistake. For example :g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
  EdgeLabels -> {1 <-> 2 -> 5, 2 <-> 3 -> 7}]                                                          g = VertexReplace[g, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B"}]

Comment: @Salahuddin Can you give me a small example where vertex renaming removes edge weights?  Your example above doesn't have edge weights at all.

Comment: @Salahuddin With a clearer mind in the morning, I think I see what you mean. Those are not *edge weights*. They are edge labels. They cannot be used in computation. The `EdgeWeight` property does get correctly preserved (unlike the `EdgeLabels` property). It would help if you have a complete and correct example in your next question (see http://sscce.org/)